How to cite a printed map in biblatex?
There is a "Map" entry type in Zotero, but it can be export to biblatex only as @misc without scale field and it renders (biblatex-chicago) in a very strange way, without editors names.
Any ideas how to reference a map with editors, scale, publisher, year in biblatex (preferably chicago)?
